# iOS Chat SDK Zendesk Build error: "___isOSVersionAtLeast", referenced from: "

Tags: zendesk-api, zendesk-app

ZenDesk iOS sdk instaling error - iPad

I am getting the following build error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"___isOSVersionAtLeast", referenced from:
"___isOSVersionAtLeast", referenced from: -[ZDCRatingCommentEditor viewWillLayoutSubviews] 
in ZDCChat(ZDCRatingCommentEditor.o) -[ZDCChatView layoutSubviews] in 
ZDCChat(ZDCChatView.o) -[ZDCTextEntryView layoutSubviews] in 
ZDCChat(ZDCTextEntryView.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker 
command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have looked for anything in the code related to ___isOSVersionAtLeast but the finder comes back with nothing. I have also installed via the route mentioned in https://help.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/229489548 as well as installing via a pod. I receive the same build error.

I have contacted ZenDesk but with no reply yet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Please share the code you are using to include the sdk, version of xcode, version of SDK being used, if it's only Chat or also Support SDK, and iOS version building for?  Have you tried installing on iPhone and had the same issues?  I've included this before and gotten it to work.

Comment: Resolved:  I was using xcode 8.3 which does not "use the new feature available in XCode 9: if (@available(iOS 11.0, *))" - https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2384080 - .  I just had to update xcode to a version >= 9.0